# Is instantiating a class in VM, MVVM compliant ? How else if so?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a contentpage and a ContentView with the content property bound to the view model

MainPage:
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage x:Class="MvvM.Views.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvM.Views"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MvvM.ViewModels">
  <!--  ViewModel BindingContext  -->
  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel />
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <!--  Header Row  -->
      <RowDefinition Height="50" />
      <!--  ContentView Row  -->
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--  Header  -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
          BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <!--  Button On Header  -->
      <Button Command=""
              Text="Page Switch"
              VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Button.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Command="TapGestureCommand" />
        </Button.GestureRecognizers>
      </Button>
    </Grid>

    <!--  Content Container  -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Center">
      <ContentView Content="{Binding DisplayPage}" />
    </Grid>

  </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

`

ViewModel:

```
`using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
 using System.Text;
 using MvvM.Views;
 using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MvvM.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            DisplayPage = new Views.MainPage();
        }

        private ContentPage _displayPage;
        public ContentPage DisplayPage
        {
            get { return _displayPage; }
            set 
            {
                if (value != _displayPage)
                {
                    _displayPage = value;
                }
            }

        }



        private ContentView _contentToDisplayView;

        public ContentView SelectedView
        {
            get => _contentToDisplayView;
            set
            {
                _contentToDisplayView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            } 
        }

        public Command TapGestureCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(TapGesture);

            }
        }

        private void TapGesture()
        {
            _contentToDisplayView = new RedView();
            _displayPage.Content = _contentToDisplayView.Content;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }

        #region PropertyChangedHandler
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
#endregion
    }
}`
```

and the second page called "RedPage" want to access the content from

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView x:Class="MvvM.Views.RedView"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MvvM.ViewModels"
             BindingContext="vm:MainViewModel">
  <ContentView.Content>
    <Grid Width="*"
          Height="*"
          BackgroundColor="Red" />
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView> `
```

The outcome I want is the ContentView content on the RedPage to be displayed in the mainpage contentview.

- is creating an instance of the redpage in the view model MVVM complaint ? (I feel that this would tightly bind view to view model?)

  - how else can i get the content property on red page into the view model ?(cant bind it and sets elements in it as you can only set content property once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would want the ViewModel not to know anything about the View and vice versa, so from that perspective this is not something you would want.

To overcome this, you would want ViewModel-to-ViewModel navigation. So, you just specify to which ViewModel you want to go and the associated View will be loaded. You can implement this manually, and depending on your chosen implementation you would have some way of resolving a View that is linked to that ViewModel.

One way to do this would be by naming conventions and reflection. This means you name all your pages like:

- MyPage
- YourPage
- OurPage

And all the ViewModels like:

- MyPageModel
- YourPageModel
- OurPageModel

Then with reflection you can simply strip off the "Model" suffix and resolve the page from there. Note that I use the Page and PageModel naming, but of course this works for View and ViewModel as well. After you do, you will still have to account for the navigation to and from this views, is it modal or not, etc.

While you can implement all of this manually it would probably be worth while to look into a MVVM framework. The method I just described is how [FreshMvvm](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm) does this for instance. But there are other good frameworks out there like Prism, Exrin, MvvmCross, etc.

Comment: I've taken a look at FRESHMVVM and looks like it will fit the bill. I'm on mobile so can't look into it too much but, the website states pages, and pageModels how difficult will it be to use view and ViewModels ?

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much .

Comment: "Ideally you would want the ViewModel not to know anything about the View and vice versa" View has to know about ViewModel, how else would it bind to it and to specific properties?

Comment: Haha you’re right. It’s not completely true. The view model needs to be connected to the view, so the view will know about the view model. But imho it shouldn’t reference it any other way than only setting the bindingcontext

Comment: looking in to this more and i'm not sure that i explained it well / FreshMVVM will help. I want one fixed contentPage, that will have a ContentView on it, the content property of this (via view model) needs to be set to that of a number of different views (set via buttons). I do not want to navigate away from the orginal contentpage (meaning freshMVVM navigation system is pointless here ?), but instead some how change the view that is bound with the contentview, so will require the content view (the second page) content property to be exposed and then assigned to the property bound on the 1st.

Comment: I’d be happy to help. Do you care to elaborate?

Comment: sorry, i pressed return to enter a new line and it sent a half edited message

Comment: if it makes it any clearer i have reframed it and posted it on the xamarin site aswell https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/126374/accessing-an-element-property-that-cant-be-bound-in-a-mvvm-compilant-way/p1?new=1